# How to split DataTable if columns are greater than 1024?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, datatable, dataset

I have Data table having 3k and more columns , as we all know that SQL Tables does not support more than 1024 Columns .I will be having this another table for it .

I just need to split DataTable if columns are greater than 1024.

I need an efficient way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Copy and then delete columns > 1024.

Comment: That's one scary table. More than 3k columns.

Comment: @jdweng : thank you , will try this

Comment: @RyanWilson : this data table is created by parsing excel which is shared by end user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never seen database table with such a big number of columns.
I do not know, how many rows does your DataTable typically have. You could [transpose DataTable](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44274/Transpose-a-DataTable-using-C) or below is a code snippet how to split DataTable. I used @jdweng idea with copy table with al values and then delete unwanted columns backwards. I cannot assess if this is the most efficient way. I did not test it on DataTable with rows.

```
static List<DataTable> SplitTables(DataTable largeTable)
{
    var tables = new List<DataTable>();
    int chunkSize = 1024;
    int cycles = largeTable.Columns.Count / chunkSize;

    for (int i = 0; i <= cycles; i++)
    {
        var tempTable = largeTable.Copy();
        for (int j = largeTable.Columns.Count - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            if (!(j >= i * chunkSize && j < (i + 1) * chunkSize))
            {
                tempTable.Columns.RemoveAt(j);
            }
        }
        tables.Add(tempTable);
    }
    return tables;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read about *normalization*, as typically properly normalized database does not require tables with 1024+ columns. If will not help, you question can be solved by e.g.

1) count number of columns

```
SELECT count(*)
    FROM information_schema.columns c
        JOIN information_schema.tables t ON c.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME
        AND c.table_schema = t.table_schema
    WHERE table_type = 'base table'  
        and c.table_name ='table_name_here'
```

2) if more than expected - create a new table

```
CREATE TABLE new_table_name_here
    (...)
```

Comment: this data table is created by parsing excel which is shared by end user